# CQ5 Programmatically Run a Workflow

Tags: servlets, workflow, aem

I created a workflow, in CQ, that needed to be run programmatically via XHR.

As many of you may know, CQ Documentation isn't the greatest (at least for this point). How can I run it programmatically ?

Comment: Note that, as this changes server state, using POST would be better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After poking around for a while I wrote a servlet that runs a Workflow Model.

Here is the code with comments:

```
@Component
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/runmodel"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET")
})
public class RunWorkflowModel extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    static private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunWorkflowModel.class);

    @Reference
    private WorkflowService workflowService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
        Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

        /* Get Parameters
         * @param path = path you want to run the workflow on
         * @param model = workflow model name you want to run.  Typically found in /etc/workflow/models
         */
        RequestParameterMap params = request.getRequestParameterMap();
        String path = params.getValue("path").getString();
        String model = params.getValue("model").getString();

        // Create a workflow session 
        WorkflowSession wfSession = workflowService.getWorkflowSession(session);
        try {
            // Get the workflow model
            WorkflowModel wfModel = wfSession.getModel(model);                
            // Get the workflow data
            // The first param in the newWorkflowData method is the payloadType.  Just a fancy name to let it know what type of workflow it is working with.
            WorkflowData wfData = wfSession.newWorkflowData("JCR_PATH", path);
            // Run the Workflow.
            wfSession.startWorkflow(wfModel, wfData);
        } catch (WorkflowException ex) {
            response.getWriter().write("failed");
            log.error("Error starting workflow.", ex);
        }

        response.getWriter().write("success");
    }
}
```

Here is the Ajax call

```
CQ.Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "/bin/runmodel",
    method: "GET",
    params : { 
        "path"  : "/content/path to item you want the workflow run on",
        "model" : "/etc/workflow/models/name of model/jcr:content/model"
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        CQ.Notification.notifyFromResponse(response);
    }
});
```