# Can't update a cq5 workflow to get the current state.

Tags: java, servlets, workflow, aem, crx

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233798/cq5-programmatically-run-a-workflow) tutorial to write a workflow for 3 HTML forms (without using CQ5 form component and CQ5 workflow submit button). I use this code to write Process step handling for my workflow:

```
public class MyProcess implements WorkflowProcess {

    public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession session,
            MetaDataMap map) throws WorkflowException {
        boolean advanced = false;

        Boolean goBack = map.get("goBack", Boolean.class);
        List<Route> routes = null;
        if (goBack == null || goBack == false) {
             routes = session.getRoutes(item);
        } else {
            routes = session.getBackRoutes(item);
        }

        for (Route route : routes) {
            LOG.info("===============================");
            LOG.info("Rout name: " + route.getName());
            LOG.info("Destinations: ");
            for (WorkflowTransition dest: route.getDestinations()) {
                LOG.info("dest: " + dest.getTo().getTitle());
            }
            LOG.info("===============================");
            if (route.hasDefault()) {
                String fromTitle = item.getNode().getTitle();
                String toTitle = route.getDestinations().get(0).getTo()
                        .getTitle();
                session.complete(item, route);
                LOG.info("===============================");
                LOG.info(item.getId() + " advanced from " + fromTitle
                        + " to " + toTitle);
                LOG.info("===============================");
                advanced = true;
            }
        }
        // fallback if no route was marked as default
        if (!advanced) {
            session.complete(item, routes.get(0));
            String fromTitle = item.getNode().getTitle();
            String toTitle = routes.get(0).getDestinations().get(0).getTo()
                    .getTitle();
            LOG.info("===============================");
            LOG.info(item.getId() + " advanced from " + fromTitle + " to "
                    + toTitle);
            LOG.info("===============================");
        }
    }

}
```

My question is: after i use `session.complete` to advance to next step, how can i refresh the workflow session to reach the current step information.

Comment: Not sure but I think what you are trying to do is based on some parameter passed in metadata map you are deciding whether to proceed to next step or to go back to previous step, ideally these logic should be written in the workflow process model and not in the individual workflow process i.e. in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think @yashahuja is correct. I was poking around and on the aem 'working with workflow' page I found some information about persisting data throw workflow steps using MetaDataMap.

From this page: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html

**"Use workflow metadata to persist information that is required during the lifetime of the workflow. A common requirement of workflow steps is to persist data for future use in the workflow, or to retrieve the persisted data.**

**Workflow metadata is stored in a MetaDataMap object. The Java API provides the Workflow.getMetaDataMap method that returns the MetaDataMap object. Also, the WorkItem.getWorkflowData method returns a WorkflowData object that provides the same getMetaDataMap object.**

**Therefore, the workflow MetaDataMap object is available to the OSGi service or ECMA script of a step component."**

example:

```
public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession session, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {

    MetaDataMap wfd = item.getWorkflow().getMetaDataMap();

    wfd.put("mykey", "My Step Value");

    Set<String> keyset = wfd.keySet();
    Iterator<String> i = keyset.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        Object key = i.next();
        log.info("The workflow medata includes key {} and value {}",key.toString(),wfd.get(key).toString());
    }
```