# Queue of workflows' launchers

Tags: aem

I am working on AEM6, but this problem is also applicable to previous version of the platform.
I have noticed that default workflows "DAM Update Asset" and "DAM Parse Word Documents" are started by launchers `/etc/workflow/launcher/config/update_asset_create` and `/etc/workflow/launcher/config/parse_word_docx_create`. These workflows are always started in the same order (`parse word docx` is started after `update asset create`). I wanted to implement similar functionality, so I created my own workflow with one process and then created launcher very similar to docx parser launcher.

The problem is that my launcher starts before default DAM Update Asset workflow. Is there any way to set an order of the launchers?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to avoid depending on this behavior. Instead, why not invoke your processes as part of the DAM Update Asset workflow?

Comment: I also have bad experience with launchers, but DAM Update Asset is the default workflow and I would like to avoid customizing it's behaviour. Everything works fine if I add my process to DAM Update Asset, but it doesn't sound as a good approach for me, especially when it is potentially possible to avoid customization.

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about customizing this workflow. It is a very common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the Process Step inside one workflow, and on the basis of completion of one task you can invoke other workflow from inside it. Please Refer this Answer : [CQ5 Programmatically Run a Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233798/cq5-programmatically-run-a-workflow) .

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not resolve the problem. The main question is: is it possible to create a queue of launchers, set fixed order of running them or at least set a dependency that one workflow launcher should be started after a workflow is completed? From my side, it can be done even programmatically, but it should be rather some kind of 'wait' step as the first step of waiting workflow than customization of  the first workflow.